# Latest Version of Chrome Broke fix background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using stellar.js  and also am using background-attachment: fixed. However, that scrolling effect which was produced suddenly stopped working in Google Chrome. Here's a link to the
 [site](http://goo.gl/kLnrqQ).

When i try to preview my website in version 45.0.2454.85 m background attachment wont work to any of my background pictures. However it works in firefox, edge and others. When i tried a version below 45 it also worked just fine.

here's how i typically create my background images

CSS

```
.intro {

background-image: url(/img/banner-bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100%;
background-attachment: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-size: contain;

}
```

HTML

```
<section class="intro" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">   </section>
```

Comment: You should add relevant code not just a link

Comment: I added the code for my background-images. I searched for similar topics but i can not solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that to make it work for this version i had to take out the `overflow-x:hidden` property from:

`html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}`

Otherwise my images won't stay fixed at this Chrome Version for a reason i don't know.